# Any good tips for App-book library?

Tags: ios, app-store

I've already released several app-books for children and the number of books is quite big.

What I want to do is create a book-stand (like news stand in iOS) and get the book together.

I think there is no way to get my apps in one app(the book-stand...) so I'm trying to remake all my previous work(the app-books) and create new app(book stand).

However, each app-book has its own interactive objects so I have no idea how to do this.

Is there any good document or any tips for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can your books be made via iBooks Author? How are they interactive? If you have to go down the custom store route, I would look at epub and HTML5.

Check out the Baker Framework or HPub. Also check out various interactive PDF SDKs out there.